# How to open .int files (using Python)

Tags: python, image, integer

I have .int files [Black and White Silicon Graphics Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Graphics_Image) containing visual information. I have two options. One, I can open .int files using an image viewer software and convert them to another format like .png. Second, I can open the file with Python and use them directly. I have tried the following software to open:

irfanview, gimp, xnview, ffmpeg, imagemagick, cognaxon wsq viewer, idx biosuite wsq viewer.

None of them can open the .int files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you willing to post a link to one, or send me one at timr at probo dot com?  PIL can open most raw formats, if you can describe it.

Comment: "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp) PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'E:/*****.int'

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're going to be impressed by this.

This is not a Silicon Graphics image file, even though it borrows the same extension.  What you have here is a biometric file, containing fingerprint, iris, or facial recognition data.  The basic format is described in this ANSI standard, https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=910136.

The headers say it is facial recognition data.  From the file, I can tell you who it is, when it was taken, where it was taken, what agency took it, and what resolution the data is.  However, the standard really only specifies how to describe the data.  It isn't raster data in the traditional sense.  It may be encoded with facial markers, or it may be compressed in some way.  I've already spent more time than I should.

If you know where this came from, then you can probably find out what facial recognition software created it.  If you just came across this, then you are at a dead end.  You now know what it IS, but not how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use File Viewer Plus 4 in Windows

```
https://fileviewerplus.com/download
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pillow python package to open such image format

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('path to your image')
```

in the `open` method read the images by their content, not by their filenames.

Comment: "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'E:/*****.int'

Comment: I checked that, and I could open such files. anyway, you can use this windows app https://file.org/free-download/sap-veviewer